# Running huggingface transformers in a docker container

Tags: docker, fastapi, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to wrap REST API (Fast API) around a huggingface transformer model. I can load the model into the server but whenever I call the prediction endpoint at `/sentiment` the docker container stops, other endpoints that don't use the model works fine.

Does anyone have any pointers at potential issues?

You'll find the full source code is found here: https://github.com/honungsburk/fastapi-huggingface-template/tree/docker-crashes

It uses:

- [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)
- [Huggingface Transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/)
- [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)
- [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)

I build and then run the container like so:

```
docker build --target production -t classifier .
docker build -t classifier .
```

The output is:

```
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

when I call `/sentiment` the docker container simply stops. I've checked the docker desktop app and it has 8GB of available RAM, the model takes 0.5GB. What could be a possible cause?

Comment: In https://github.com/honungsburk/fastapi-huggingface-template/blob/d7ec5b43e7525691d16f19b4552a99e7efc5d703/src/app.py#L23 add a `print(e)` to see what's happening

Comment: also for better insight add the necessary sources to the question than mentioning the link for the project

Comment: Do you happen to be running this on Apple Silicon? I ran in to a very similar issue for days trying on my M2 Mac, and just found out today that it works okay on Intel Macs. I posted an issue about it here if you're curious, https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/10640 any luck getting it to work on your end yet?